# Changing a stopword dictionary on Heroku's Postgres service?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, full-text-search, stop-words

Postgres documentation [describes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SIMPLE-DICTIONARY) setting a different stop word list for full text search by putting a file on disk.  As an example, the default `english` stopword file is at `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/english.stop`.

If I use the [managed Postgres service on Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), can I even access the file system for Postgres?

How do I change the stop list used for full text search?

Comment: You probably can't, unless Heroku did some heavy tinkering with the code.  That is the cost of using Whatever As A Service.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm figuring, too. Perhaps the best option for me is to make new columns pre-processed to drop stop words before loading.